# R: how to remove \n and <br /> from text data

Tags: regex, r

I have a text data like the following:

```
   hold that\nagainst me. i spend most of my days trying to build cool stuff for\nmy company. <br />\n<br />\ni'm an entrepreneur (like everyone else in sf, it seems) and i love\nwhat i do.
```

I used the following command but it has only removed \n and  still remains.

```
   gsub("\n <br />", " ", h)
```

and when I tried this command, both of the characters are removed but the "re" in the actual text data is also removed. So, I am wondering what is a proper way to remove both.

```
 gsub("[\n <br />]", " ", h)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  text <- "hold that\nagainst me. i spend most of my days trying to build cool stuff for\nmy company. <br />\n<br />\ni'm an entrepreneur (like everyone else in sf, it seems) and i love\nwhat i do."
```

Use `(pat1|pat2)` to select different patterns (`[]` only works for single-character alternatives).

```
 gsub("(\n|<br />)"," ",text)
 ## [1] "hold that against me. i spend most of my days trying to build cool stuff for my company.     i'm an entrepreneur (like everyone else in sf, it seems) and i love what i do."
```

Comment: One does not have to escape the `\n`. Also, it is better to match optional whitespaces between `br` and `>`, and allow an optional `/`: [`gsub("[\n\r]|<br\\s*/?>", "", text)`](http://ideone.com/V3jwfP)

Comment: can you tell me why allowing these characters is better? I am new to text data.